# Parse.com: PFQuery querying data from PFUser currentUser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parse-platform

In my iOS app, I am using the Parse.com framework. When the app is launched for the first time or the user isn't signed in, the `PFLogInViewController` and the `PFSignUpViewController` will show up on the view. When the user creates his/her account, the application will automatically create the user, like always, but it will also create another variable under the user which is  called `isPrivate`, which calls for a boolean. My question is how do I use the `PFQuery` to get the value of `isPrivate` for the `currentUser`?

Comment: PFUser has its own method [PFUser query] to query users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Querying helps you find many objects matching a criteria. This doesn't really apply when you already know the object you want (the current user). You can decide whether the currentUser is private with

```
[PFUser.currentUser[@"isPrivate"] boolValue];
```

Though in this particular case, you don't actually need to keep a separate field to determine whether the user is an anonymous user (the type created by automatic users). Try:

```
[PFAnonymousUtils isLinkedWithUser:PFUser.currentUser];
```

This works for all authentication utils (PFFacebookUtils, PFTwitterUtils, and PFAnonymousUtils). isLinkedWithUser determines whether those auth systems have credentials for a particular user.

Comment: Lets say I also have another variable that is an array, how would I do this with an Array?

Comment: If you're trying to get the value from a particular object, then you can assume that you'll get an NSArray back when you get that property (i.e. NSArray *property = myObj[@"arrayProperty"]). Otherwise, you can  use a PFQuery isEqualTo. Comparing a scalar against an array returns objects where the scalar is in the array (e.g. This is most common with PFInstallation, where cloud code might check subscribers of "channel" by checking where the "channels" array is equal to "channel").

Comment: Everything is working great, but when I try [[PFUser.currentUser [@"Nickname"]stringValue];. The console prints out: "-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance". What I am I doing wrong?

Comment: boolValue is required to turn an NSNumber (object) into a BOOL (primitive), but currentUser[@"nickname"] is already an NSString. You don't need any stringValue method.

Comment: Thanks, just one more question: when you are using the PFUser.currentUser, it gets it data locally, not from parse.com, correct?

Comment: Correct. If you wanted to get the parse.com version of the data, you can call refresh. This is true of any cached object.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with everything.

Answer (score 6):

After playing around with PFObject, PFUser, and PFQuery, I found the answer to my question.
You have to create a PFQuery the queries the PFUser class, then you have to narrow the query down to only the `currentUser username`, then you request the value of `isPrivate`.

```
PFQuery *query= [PFUser query];

[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){

    BOOL isPrivate = [[object objectForKey:@"isPrivate"]boolValue];

}];
```

Comment: So, I am attempting to query a PFUser by 'name' instead of 'username'. For some reason, the query doesn't work. Is there something I may be doing wrong? I use basically the exact same code as you but I don't get any results... :(

Comment: @jsetting32 There could be a couple things happening, and with out the code or more background information it will be just poking around in the dark, but a couple things that it could be is in second line of code, make sure the exact key exists in the Parse.com data browser and make sure you have the 'name' correct, ie: the same as the one under the key in Parse.com data browser that you described. Other area I see that can be causing you problems is the third line of code, inside the block of code... (Ran out of characters).